# Fabric distribution issue (We couldn't locate the following devices in your profile)

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I registered new device in developer.apple.com and after generation all profiles when I tried to send the build caught this issue: "We couldn't locate the following devices in your profile... Use this file to update missing UDIDs in your ... development profile in the Apple iOS Provisioning". But this UDID is not missed. I tried to disable it, generate all profiles, enable it and generate again. Also I tried to delete old profiles and create new. Nothing changed. All other devices works fine. If I try to install this build via Beta app - "developer needs to add this device's UDID to a build". How can I fix it?

I guess it may happen because we had another device with the same name but different UDID. I renamed it before adding new one. But in that message I see not the same name as in devices list. But I'm not sure that that's the reason why it doesn't work. I tried to disable that old device at all and generate profiles again but it doesn't help too

Comment: device naming is not the issue. How are you making build? local machine, server? does that machine have right cert and profiles?

Comment: local machine. it contains all certificates and profiles. I solved it. just deleted all *. mobileprovision files from ../Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and download them again

Comment: Please add your comment in answers and marked as answered. It could be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I solved it. just deleted all *. mobileprovision files from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` and download them again

Comment: I wonna burn down twitter head quarter to the ground now.

Comment: And those ... at apple's

Comment: I had to do this too...oddly, after redoing everything, those files don't come back...

Comment: Deleted profiles. Downloading the profiles again did not work for me. If "Automatically manage Signing" is not checked in your project general tab in Xcode, you will likely have to check it and uncheck it.

Comment: I lost an hour of my life to this. Luckily your solution worked

Comment: The fact that this works is freaking insane. But thank you so much for reporting this!

Comment: I've come back to this like 4 times because I can never remember what folder it's in. But I would like to point out that this isn't a Fabric issue, but rather an iOS/xcode issue. Although the Fabric app could (and should) probably clean out the profiles dir automatically for us.