# Added Testing devices or Beta users in fabric Crashlytics not able to download App

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I am using fabric Crashlytics to deployed beta app but not able to download app.

error:

> The developer needs to add this device's UDID to the build.

[image]

I am able to upload build on fabric Crashlytics using Fastfile script.

Tried solutions :

1. First send the invitation to become Beta tester and add devices then using device UDID's to add in Fastfile manually but its not working :

Fastfile :

```
lane :beta do
  # build your iOS app
  gym(
    # scheme: "YourScheme",
    export_method: "ad-hoc"
  )

  # upload to Beta by Crashlytics
  crashlytics(
    api_token: "*****************************************",
    build_secret: "*****************************************"
  )
  register_devices(
    devices: {
      'ABC' => '*****************************************',
      'BCD' => '*****************************************',
      'XYZ' => '*****************************************'

    }
  )
end
```

2. Added Devices in https://developer.apple.com/ Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section.
3. From Xcode deleted developer account and added again and also downloaded All Provisioning Profiles.
4. Removed Beta tester and added again.
5. After adding new Beta user or Devices new app uploaded again but same error **The developer needs to add this device's UDID to the build.**

But all solutions not working for me.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What do you see in the output after running the register devices action or Beta lane.

Comment: @MikeBonnell fastlane beta command shows devices registered successfully

Comment: Hmm, even stranger. Can you try deleting all local provisioning profiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles and then do a new distribution and let me know how that goes? It sounds like Xcode is providing a cached old profile.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for the response. Yes, it's problem with provisioning profiles. Every time new device added I need to update provisioning profile with new devices and download again to add testers.I am posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After following all the documentation how to add Beta build with beta tester to fabric Crashlytics don’t forgot to update your provisioning profile and download again to update added devices on  http://developer.apple.com. If you don’t update provisioning profile with new added devices it will not add new devices for testing environment.

1. Sign in to http://developer.apple.com.
2. Click on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" in the right sidebar.
3. Click on "Devices", then on the + button.
4. Select "Register Multiple Devices" and choose the downloaded device file.
5. Click on "Continue".
6. Confirm the list of imported devices with "Register".
7. Click on "Distribution" below "Provisioning Profiles".
8. Click on the + button, select "Ad Hoc", then click on "Continue".
9. Select the App ID for your app, then click on "Continue". If you have no corresponding App ID, please follow Apple’s documentation: Registering App IDs.
10. Select your certificate, then click on "Continue". If you have not yet created a certificate, please follow Apple’s documentation: Creating Signing Identities. Notice that you need a distribution certificate for ad-hoc distribution.
11. Now you should see all devices registered in the portal. Select all or just the ones that you want to include in this provisioning profile. Then click on "Continue".
12. Enter a name for the profile. Confirm with "Generate". The portal will now show "Loading…" for some time, then you can download the profile.
13. Drag & drop the downloaded profile to Xcode.
14. In Xcode, select your project in the left sidebar, then "Build Settings".
15. Enter "code sign" in the search field.
16. Select the line for your release configuration and choose the downloaded profile.
17. **Most Important : Always update your  provisioning profile with newly added devices UDID and download again in Xcode to update list of devices.**
18. Create a build through "Product > Archive".
19. Or Using fastlane beta directly upload build.
    Finally, upload the new build to fabric Crashlytics and notify your testers.

Add new devices to  http://developer.apple.com update providing profiles and update providing profiles in Xcode then release new Beta version.

Comment: very helpfull to have all the steps, thanks!

considering how cumbersome is the process (mainly on the Apple tools side) I wonder if it is possible to list the udids of the devices to be used by fastlane i.e. from command line

Comment: I tried everything from adding device to profile, downloaded profile in Xcode, regenerate build, deleted and added tester again but new tester doesn’t see the install button when tapping “Check out” email. I have migrated to firebase so could that have messed up something ? If so what do I do? Please help.

Comment: Found solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43660816/430690